# Regexp: capture multiple patterns inside a matching pattern

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to find a regexp that captures both `1 member` and `# members` from the following text:

```
"{count, plural, =1 {1 member} other {# members}}"
```

I've tried with `/{.*{(.*)}.*}/` but that only captures `# members`. If it helps, I'm using Ruby as my language.

Comment: `s.scan(/{([^{}]*)}/)`?

Comment: Maybe `{[^{}]*}`? If you need to extract what comes between braces enclose them in parentheses.

Comment: yes, that works @WiktorStribiżew. Thanks. I you put it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @revo that also captures `{` and `}`, which I don't want. But it's close enough! Thanks

Comment: I added an answer at the linked question for which this is a dup that uses lookarounds rather than a capture group and considers the possibility of nested pairs of braces.